# Pattern matching for custom read function

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am writing a custom read function for one of the data types in my module. For eg, when I do `read "(1 + 1)" :: Data`, I want it to return `Plus 1 1`. My data declaration is `data Data = Plus Int Int`. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. Your topic mentions pattern matching, but the body of the question does not. You say you're writing a custom read function, but you don't say which problem you encountered doing so.

Comment: the problem is I want to do some pattern matching with the string. Eg: if the string is "(1 + 1)" then it will return Plus 1 1. If it is "(2 - 1)" it returns Minus 2 1. The operators can be + - * /. And the operands can be any integers. But the operator must be bounded by spaces and there must be brackets bounded the whole expression.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like something better suited to a parser; [Parsec](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsec) is a powerful Haskell parser combinator library, which I would recommend.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to second the notion of using a parser. However, if you absolutely have to use a pattern-matching, go like this:

```
import Data.List

data Expr = Plus Int Int | Minus Int Int deriving Show

test = [ myRead "(1 + 1)", myRead "(2-1)" ]

myRead = match . lexer
  where
    match ["(",a,"+",b,")"] = Plus (read a) (read b)
    match ["(",a,"-",b,")"] = Minus (read a) (read b)
    match garbage           = error $ "Cannot parse " ++ show garbage

lexer = unfoldr next_lexeme
  where 
    next_lexeme ""  = Nothing
    next_lexeme str = Just $ head $ lex str
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use GHC's [ReadP](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.0/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html).